# Secure password reset without sending an e-mail

Tags: php, security, passwords

How do I go about implementing a secure password reset function without sending the user an e-mail? There is another secure bit of information that I store and only the user should know, but it seems insecure to just let the user update a password just because they know a 9 digit number.

Note that user data is stored in a simple SQL table due to limitations on real database users on the server I'm working on.

Any input would be appreciated.

**Update:**
After making an attempt at OpenID and remembering that this server doesn't allow PHP (and thus, cURL) to make any external requests, I tried sending mail with PHP again. Apparently all of my previous terrible experiences with mail() on this server have gone away.

Thanks for all of your input, I may look into OpenID again in the future.

Comment: Does it feel insecure because the 9-digit number happens to be their phone number?

Comment: digits olny is weak. use alphanumeric, upper and lower case

Comment: Phone numbers are 10 digits in North America.  I'm guessing it's a SSN.

Comment: Does it feel insecure because you KNOW it, and can't just verify it?  Because it should.  You should only be storing a hash of any information that has login-type power (resetting a password counts).

Comment: That would be a 10 digit number.... (123)-456-7890

Comment: It actually a university student number. (womp is closest)

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't rely that no-one else knows that.  Since it's printed on forms that a student may toss, and a lucky dumpster-diver may find.

Comment: @rampion - they would also have to know their website username, which I don't think is ever actually printed. Also, I don't store their real names in the user table; they're exported to an offline csv file for the rare case that I need to connect their username to real name. But still, I'm considering other options.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Good security is hard, it deserves thorough consideration.  Their website username may not be printed, but it may be predictable by an attacker - [FirstInitial][MiddleInitial][LastName][Number]?  Or, if set by a user, [CommonUsernameTheyUseOnEverySiteEver]?

Comment: Actually, I tell them to use their university login name, so most are 3 letters followed by 4 numbers, not sequential. Older ones are [firstInital][1-9][lastName].

Comment: Right, so these are predictable.  Plus, I'll bet they university gives them an email address using that login name?  In any case, I'm just trying to make the argument that guessing the website username for a student, given that you've already found their real name and student number wouldn't be hard.

Comment: Nope, the login name has nothing to do with the e-mail address. And the old-style login names with [firstInitial][1-9][lastname] are no longer issued and will be gone from my system in the next 2 years. Also, I get what your saying, its just that a lot of your assumptions are wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Punt on the password issue.  Switch to OpenID.  You don't have to worry about password reset, and the user only needs a new password if they want one.

it's a win-win.

Comment: It not an open registration. It's only for specific people.

Comment: How are you verifying that it's only these people creating accounts?  You can do that verification AND use OpenID.  E.g. - The superuser beta uses OpenID, but only those with a password can use it.

Comment: OpenID doesn't mean that registration is open, just which protocol is used for identification.

Comment: @hobodave - I'd say rethinking your requirements is applicable to the question.

Comment: Hmm...is there a good way to let the user opt to use the "legacy" authentication system, if you will, or let them use OpenID? or should I start another question?

Comment: Another question might help you with specifics, but you could create an "add an OpenID to this account" feature (similar to how StackOverflow does it) for existing members.

Comment: Marked as answer due to the fact that it made me try mail() again, also made me think about trying harder for OpenID in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, identifying a user as being real on the internet requires an "opt in" model where the user "opts" to have their password reset, and an email is sent confirming that they either want it reset, or that is has been reset and what the new reset password is.

Really, the only reasonably safe alternatives are ones that use a similar method.  Send an email, sms text message they must reply to, automated phone call where they have to punch in digits, etc.

The only method I can think of that doesn't use this system would be a security question.  Banks often use these for additional verification when users log in or fail to log in correctly a number of times.  They are sometimes also used as a "secret" code for retrieving a password, but even then, it is typically emailed to the user, not displayed on the page.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of your answer are spot-on but the last is awful. "Security Questions" are *unacceptably* insecure. They are the most vulnerable attack vector in a system - do not use them!

Comment: I would hardly consider his paragraph awful. Only the OP can determine what is "acceptably" secure for his application's needs. Given his reluctance/inability to send an email, this is a suitable alternative.

Comment: I agree that security questions are not very secure which is why I said they're usually only used for additional verification.  It is a last resort sort of thing, the only method I could think of that didn't use email.

Answer (score 1):

You have no way of knowing who is trying reset "Joe's" password. It could be Joe, or could be someone posing as Joe.

An alternative to sending an email is to either call one of Joe's phones with a one-time reset key or send an SMS message.

Calling Joe's phone with an audio message is easy with http://www.twilio.com/ But anyone might be able to pick up Joe's office phone. So usually you'd want an additional challenge before calling. Eg a secret question/answer. By using the phone *and* the secret q&a, you've made things tougher for the bad guys but still doable by Joe.

Another idea is to send the reset message to someone that Joe trusts and who knows Joe. (Send either by email or by telephone / sms.) A variant of this is to send to an employee who knows Joe, eg his assigned salesrep, HR rep, etc.

Use the post: Send a snail mail letter with the reset code in it. Would take a couple of days to get there, but theft of mail is a federal rap. See http://www.postalmethods.com/ If there are very bad possible negative outcomes, this can be a good solution.

For any of the above, Joe would enter the information when he sets up the account.

Another pattern is to require Joe to call into a help desk and let a human interrogate him.

Bottom line is that no technique is perfect. See the twitter breakin story: http://www.technewsworld.com/story/67612.html?wlc=1247790901&wlc=1248238327

Last thought: don't forget about anti-phishing. Often done by enabling Joe to choose a picture that the site will show him when doing something important. The idea is that a phishing site won't be able to replicate the UI, thus raising Joe's suspicions that he may not have arrived at the right site.

Answer (score 0):

Without sending an email you are limiting yourself significantly. One of the benefits of sending a password reset code, or new password to someone's email address is you can rely on the assumption that they are the only person with access to their email account.

That said, you could use a "Secret Question" scheme to allow someone to reset their password. When this person creates their account you need to capture their secret question and the answer. You would then prompt the user with this question, and only permit resets if they answer correctly.

I must warn you that this is not a very good method of securing their password from unauthorized access. For a good article read: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/the_curse_of_th.html

Comment: The "secret question" is the most vulnerable attack vector in a system. Best not to use it.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware of how its more secure, I'm just trying to avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: I would say that it's less that you *can* rely on single-user email, and more that everyone does.  Just b/c everyone does it, doesn't make it good.

Comment: @Rex M - see my response to your comment above. Given my caveat I provided as well as the article on the disadvantages of this method, your comment adds nothing to the discussion. You provide no alternative solution either.